# Does blending work with the GLSL mix function

Tags: opengl, glsl

These are my blending functions.

```cpp
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glBlendEquation(GL_FUNC_ADD);
```

I mix two textures in the fragment shader using mix function.

```c
FragColor = 
    mix(texture(texture1, TexCoord), texture(texturecubeMap, ransformedR), MixValueVariables.CubeMapValue ) * 
    vec4(result, material.opacity / 100.0); // multiplying texture with material value
```

Despite changing the blend Equation or BlendFunc types i don't see any difference in the output.

Does mix function works with the blend types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does `mix` function works with the blend types.

No. [Blending](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending) and the glsl function [`mix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/mix.xhtml) are completely different things.

The function `mix(x, y, a)` calculates always `x * (1−a) + y * a`.

Blending takes the fragment color outputs from the Fragment Shader and combines them with the colors in the color buffer of the frame buffer.

If you want to use [Blending](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending), then you've to

- draw the geometry with the first texture
- activate blending
- draw the geometry with the second texture

If you just want to blend the textures in the fragment shader, then you've to use the glsl arithmetic. See [GLSL Programming/Vector and Matrix Operations](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Vector_and_Matrix_Operations)

e.g.

```c
vec4 MyBlend(vec4 source, vec4 dest, float alpha)
{
    return source * alpha + dest * (1.0-alpha);
}

void main()
{
    vec4 c1 = texture(texture1, TexCoord);
    vec4 c2 = texture(texturecubeMap, ransformedR);
    float f = MixValueVariables.CubeMapValue

    FragColor = MyBlend(c1, c2, f) * vec4(result, material.opacity / 100.0); 
}
```

Adapt the function `MyBlend` to your needs.

Comment: is it possible to use blend in glsl.

Comment: @shomit: Not really. The fragment shader and blending happen at two separate stages in the pipeline. There are techniques which allow for programmatic blending, but they tend to carry a performance hit, and they're not easy to code. They're certainly not automatic.